# Splitting a string in Java in a specific way and storing it an array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to split the string `"ABCD"` into an array which will hold the values `["AB","BC","CD"]`, but I am unsure how to go about this.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: So you want help in java syntax or algorithm?

Comment: Did you examine the [documentation of String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to see which of its methods can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

```
String string1 = "ABCD";

for(int i = 0; i < string1.length() - 1; i++){
    String string2 = Character.toString(string1.charAt(i)); 
    string2 += Character.toString(string1.charAt(i+1));
    System.out.println(string2);
    }
```

What "Character.toString(string1.charAt(i))" does is basically find the character of string1's "i" value. So for example, if i = 0, string2 would equal string1's value at 0, which is "A". Then, in the next line of code, string2 adds string1's value of "i+1" (which is the next letter, so B). Therefore, it will print "AB", "BC, and "CD".

Answer (score 0):

Can be done really easily:

```
String string = "ABCDEFGH";
String[] result = new String[string.length() - 1];

for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = string.charAt(i) + "" + string.charAt(i+1);
}
```

**Variable "result" consists of:**

```
"AB"
"BC"
"CD"
"DE"
"EF"
"FG"
"GH"
```